# Flutter: converting widget to image just after setState does not show changes

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, setstate, marker

I have been struggling for some days with an issue, and I am starting to wonder if it has a decent solution.

I have a Google Map in which I want to show different custom markers, each one is created with information that comes from an API call.

To achieve this, I use a Stack widget that has a RepaintBoundary located below the Google map so it is hidden. This RepaintBoundary has an image and a text label.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      RepaintBoundary(
        key: iconKey,
        child:
        Stack(
            children: [
              markerIconButton,
              markerText,
            ]
        ),
      ),
      GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        myLocationButtonEnabled:true,
        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        markers: Set<Marker>.of(_markers),
      ),
    ]
  ),
),
```

}

When I want to place the markers, I loop through the results of the API call, and in each iteration, I try to change the image and the text of the RepaintBoundary, convert it to an image, and then assign it to the new marker, I use this piece of code:

```
...
 for (dynamic result in results) {
     ...
     markerText = result["text"];
     backgroundImage = result["assets_image_path"];
     setState((){
        markerIconButton = new Image.asset(backgroundImage);
        markerText = new Text(markerText);
      });

      // Convert the widget to image
      BitmapDescriptor testIcon = await getCustomIcon(iconKey);

      Marker marker = Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(index.toString()),
          position: LatLng(
              result["latitude"],
              result["longitude"]
          ),
          icon: testIcon,
      );

      setState((){
        _markers.add(marker);
      });
      index++;
 }
```

The problem is that when I call "getCustomIcon" that uses the RenderRepaintBoundary.toImage method, the new text and image have not been rendered yet, so the image passed as icon to the current iteration marker usually belongs to the previous iteration. Is there a way to run the code that converts the widget into an image assuring that the changes in the image and the text have been rendered?

I have tried to generate first all the images in the loop and saving them in a List using WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback, but when I remove the code for adding each marker from the loop, a lot of frames are skipped and only the image and text of the last iteration are rendered.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you let no time for the framework to build your UI before converting to image. 
setState is asynchronus and executed when the framework have the time to do it. 
Try adding a delay :
     setState((){
        markerIconButton = new Image.asset(backgroundImage);
        markerText = new Text(markerText);
      });
       Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 2000));
      // Convert the widget to image
      BitmapDescriptor testIcon = await getCustomIcon(iconKey);

Comment: I had tested this already, and it works, but it has a huge impact in terms of performance, imagine that you have 30 markers to show. Apart from that, you have no 100% guarantee that it has been rendered no matter how much time you specify in the delay. I thought there should be a way to call something after render.

Comment: yeah i agree but i have not find this way, you can probably reduce the delay, 2000ms was just an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you let no time for the framework to build your UI before converting to image. setState is asynchronus and executed when the framework have the time to do it. Try adding a delay :

```
 setState((){
    markerIconButton = new Image.asset(backgroundImage);
    markerText = new Text(markerText);
  });
  Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 2000));
  // Convert the widget to image
  BitmapDescriptor testIcon = await getCustomIcon(iconKey);
```